# In table tennis, ITTF rules, what constitutes moving the playing surface (table)?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, ittf

You lose a point if you move the table. but what does "moves" constitute? 
Is it rolling/moving leg? or as small as a vibration.

2.10.1.9 if an opponent, or anything an opponent wears or carries, moves the playing
surface;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vibration is not a move.

After a move the table, table-body or one table leg stands in a different place.

---

> This means that if you cause the table tennis table to move whilst the ball is still in play, you lose the point.
>
> This usually happens when you rush forward to play a shot. After you've played your shot, your forward momentum can cause you to move the table.
>
> However, if the ball wasn't in play when you moved the table tennis table, there's no penalty. For example, once the ball has bounced a second time (either on the table, floor, surroundings, or hits your opponent), the ball's no longer in play.

Source: [www.allabouttabletennis.com](http://www.allabouttabletennis.com/basic-table-tennis-rules.html)